# How do I tweak an entire animation in global angles and location?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I Imported a BVH of a human character walking in the y direction but it needed some adjustments.

z location of the pelvis is too high throughout the entire walk cycle. In the graph when I move vertically the z Location graph it causes the character to move 45degrees instead of straight up. Also, I want to move in rotation y the arms as they go through the hips but any tweak changes more than just y.

Then I noticed that none of the graphs represent anything in global location or rotation and it's problematic.

Maybe something to do with using Quaternions?

How do I tweak of all keyframes in global location or angles for all frames at once?

The option to use the manipulator to affect a selected range of keyframes at the same time would be a solution.

Comment: Bones have their own location and axes that are keyed using local co-ords. In the armature properties enable display axes, you will find the Y-axis is the length of the bone (so global Z would match the spines Y-axis of a standing character). The bones roll (in edit mode) controls the position of the X and Z axes, which will affect how the bone rotates. You probably want to  use python if you have multiple bones to adjust over many keyframes.

Comment: @sambler Maybe something like a Make the manipulator affect all keyframes in this range tool would be nice.

Comment: I changed the 45 degree angle of the pelvis and the root bone to right angled bones which helps with adjusting the position. But I would still like to have the option to use the manipulator to affect a range of keyframes.

Comment: I don't think we have any multi-frame keyframe editing in the 3Dview, we can select multiple keyframes in the graph editor and move them up by the same amount or with proportional falloff. You may want to contact Antonio as he just implemented something like that [for the grease pencil](https://code.blender.org/2017/12/drawing-2d-animation-in-blender-2-8/), maybe the technique can be adapted for other keys.

Comment: @sambler You can multiedit in the graph but with bones it only allows you to edit on local axis only. So here's hoping for that tool to apply to any type of animation. Thanks for the tip.