# How to rotate the arms on the x axis on a lot of keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes, graph-editor, pose-mode

I have imported an adobe fuse/mixamo character/armature/fbx file into blender and I realized that the arms pass through the thigh,as you can see here :

[image: pic 1]

I would like to rotate the arms on the x axis a little upper in pose mode,but since the animation has 288 frames,should I do it for each frame ? It will take a lot of time !!!. I changed the first and the last frame only,but the frames on the middle aren't changed. I don't know why. Is there a faster way ? thanks. You can find the fbx file [here.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JbbxiJqzQlgjRMcUBtZ09rg2e4kkGhBg)

Comment: I think this is the same problem as [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/97605/935).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the Graph Editor with the relevant bone selected in the 3D view, you can select and manipulate the handles controlling the keyframes for the particular value you want.  So for the left forearm, I think the value you may want to control is "W Quaternion Rotation".  Type A once or twice to make sure nothing is selected, then select one of the control point handles for WQuaternionRotation, then type L (select linked).  Then type G to move the values up or down for all of the keyframes.